# Get Rid of Hover Effects on a <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add some links to the app store on a webpage I'm designing. The best way to incorporate them was to add them into an existing `<ul>` object, `signin_box` and override the CSS using another `<ul>` called `app_downloads`. However, the ul has some effects when you hover over the items that causes the color of a `<li>` to change. If I could make it so that the color changes to #FFF (the background color for everything else, making it invisible) or get rid of the hover effects, it would be perfect. I've been playing around with the CSS, but nothing seems to work. Below is the CSS to deal with the two `<ul>` classes. I just want to get rid of the hover styles inherited from `signin_box` in `app-downloads`.

```
.app-downloads li {
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
}

.signin_box .app-downloads li a {
    background:  #FFF;
    border:  none;
    text-align: center;
}

.signin_box .app-downloads ul li a:hover, .signin_box .app-downloads ul li a.active {
    background-color: #FFF;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="signin_box">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <g:link controller="public" action="taketour" class="taketour"><span class="tour"></span>Take a Tour</g:link>
      </li>
      <li><a href="link to a PDF"><span class="brochur"></span>View Document</a></li>
      <li class="register">
         <g:link controller="public" action="signup" class="active">Sign Up</g:link>
      </li>
      <ul class="app-downloads">
         <li>
            <a href="link to google play app"><img alt="Google Play" height = "50" width="158" src="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/images/generic/en-play-badge.png" /><span class="googleApp"></</span></a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="iOS app link">
               <g:img  dir="images" file="Download_App.png" height = "50" width="158" alt="Download on the App Store" />
               <span class="iOS app"></span>
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css isn't working because `.app-downloads` **is** the `ul`, so this selector does not work:  `.signin_box .app-downloads ul li...`

Change it like so, and your css will work:

```
.signin_box .app-downloads li a:hover, 
.signin_box .app-downloads li a.active {
     /* styles go here */
}
```

**Bonus:**
A BETTER way to do this would be to alter the `.signin_box` styles to be more specific, so as to not affect the `.app-downloads` list.  There's a couple of ways to tackle this, and without knowing your specific project, it's hard to say if (or which) of these would work:

```
/* Modify ORIGINAL styles to be like so */
.signin_box > ul > li > a:hover {
    /* these will only affect immediate descendants, not nested lists */
}
```

OR

```
.signin_box:not(.app-downloads) ul li > a:hover {
    /* these will specifically exclude app downloads lists, BUT may still inherit, so may not be the best option */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. Please change:

```
.signin_box .app-downloads ul li
```

With:

```
.signin_box ul.app-downloads li
```

Coz the `<ul>` is the element having `.app-downloads` class and that class doesn't contain an `<ul>` inside. Your full CSS would be:

```css
.signin_box ul.app-downloads li a:hover, 
.signin_box ul.app-downloads li a.active {
  background-color: #FFF;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
}
```